# SQL AutoIncrement each day recount + User specify when insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help on some SQL insert trigger

User = A and B, Date = today, Autoincrement = reset every day

```
(Unique Key)
A160420-0001
B160420-0001
A160420-0002
A160420-0003
B160420-0004
B160420-0003
```

next day

```
A160421-0001
B160421-0001
so on...
```

possible I do that?

Thanks

Comment: on this part A1604xx will increment and not the - 0001?

Comment: is this a fixed format 'A' appended with numbers and '-' and fixed key 0001?

Comment: You could use a sequence along with a SQL job that runs at midnight that resets it. However almost every question I've seen along these lines is generating some special convoluted key for no real reason. Can you give us some background on why you need to do this?

Comment: Is this number came from date? or just a number

Comment: I have user A and B at different location, they will print a receipt with running number (unique)
but the receipt running number must be continues and not break apart like

A00001, A00004, A00006, A00010 but like 

A00001, A00002, A00003 and B00001, B00002, B00003

i know this can be easily done by create 2 table, but the problem i have many user.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn auto increment to A or B, possible? A00001, B00001, A00002...

Comment: Why don't you create 3 fields for storing data: `User - Date - Index` and unique for 3 fields. Very easy to store and modify data

Comment: So do the two users use different databases or the same database? Why does it need to reset each day? Why don't you keep it really simple and use and identity and then you can concoct any contrived key you want in a calculated column. Don't create two tables. Create one table that has the data saved in seperate fields like @TriV says, and if you must, you can stick them all together.